# Toggle not working on mobile dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm trying to make a toggle event on mobile for a dropdown menu. so when you click the link, the dropdown appears, and when you click it again it disappears. for some reason it's not working. this is my code:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
                <li class="mobile-homepage"><a (click)="selectPage('homepage')">{{'NAVIGATION_HOMEPAGE'|translate}}</a></li>
                <li><a (click)="selectPage('solutions')" class="main-links separate">{{'NAVIGATION_SOLUTIONS'|translate}}</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown set-width">
                        <li><a (click)="selectPage('solutions', 'collect')" >{{'NAVIGATION_CLICK_COLLECT'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a (click)="selectPage('solutions', 'returns')">{{'NAVIGATION_STORE_RETURNS'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a (click)="selectPage('solutions', 'aisle')" >{{'NAVIGATION_ENDLESS_AISLE'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a (click)="selectPage('solutions', 'store')" >{{'NAVIGATION_STORE_FULFILMENT'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a (click)="selectPage('solutions', 'customer')" >{{'NAVIGATION_CUSTOMER_CARE'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a (click)="selectPage('solutions', 'partner')" >{{'NAVIGATION_PARTNER_FULFILMENT'|translate}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
 if (windowWidth < 800) {
        $('nav > ul > li > a:not(.only-child').click(function(e){
            $(".nav-dropdown").hide();
            $(this).next('.nav-dropdown').slideToggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
    }
```

What's happening it that when i click it opens and slides down, but when i click it again, it doesn't slide back up, it just slide down to open again. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are first hiding _all_ `.nav-dropdown` elements, so when you try to toggle a specific one afterwards, of course it only toggles _from_ the hidden state into visible each time. There _never_ is an element in the other state at the point where you call slideToggle - you made sure of that in the previous line.

Comment: So, how would I fix that? I need to hide all .nav-dropdown elements because when i click one link, they will all open (i have multiple dropdowns) unless i specify to hide them all and only open this dropdown. and its this dropdown that i want to toggle.

Comment: Why would they _all_ open when you click a single link? That makes no sense, you are only calling slideToggle on the one specific element that follows that link. _“So, how would I fix that?”_ - you would leave the “current” item alone, and only hide all others …?

Comment: Because I have multiple dropdown menus, with the same class as .nav-dropdown. so if i just say on click dropdown open, they all will. so i have to say hide, and only open this specific one. can you show what you mean by writing it in code?

Comment: _“so if i just say on click dropdown open”_ - yeah, only you _didn’t_ say that. You are _already_ toggling the dropdown that follows the clicked link only. So with the code that you have shown, the behavior you are describing can’t really occur. Analyze and describe what is going on _properly_, please. That you need to hide/close the previously opened one is of course true - but that is a different issue. And as I said, you tried that already, you only went to far with it - hide all dropdowns that are _not_ the one following the currently clicked link.

Comment: i'm just asking for help. i'm a beginner and learning. i am analysing and describing to the best of my ability. can you show me what you mean by an example with code? i'm asking how can i change my code to make it work.

Comment: `$(".nav-dropdown").hide()` hides too many elements (because it includes the current one.) How to access to current dropdown element, you already know (because you are already doing that in the next line.) So you should be able to simply remove the current one from the list of elements to hide using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)